# Are homotopy equivalent manifolds with homeomorpic boundaries themselves homeomorphic?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, differential-topology, manifolds

Let $f:M \to M′$ be a homotopy equivalence of topological manifolds with boundary such that $dim(M)=dim(M′)$ and $f:\partial M \to \partial M′$ is a homeomorphism. Does this imply the existence of a homeomorphism $\tilde{f}:M \to M′$?

This seems too good to be true but I cannot think of any counterexamples. If it is false, what are the obstructions and are there further conditions that make the statement true?

Comment: Of course not: just let $X$ and $X'$ be homotopy equivalent but not homeomorphic 3-dimensional lens spaces and let $M$ (resp. $M'$) be the result of removing a small open ball from $X$ (resp. $X'$).  Similar things happen in higher dimensions.

Comment: @AndyPutman Does there exist a homotopy equivalence between them which restricts to a homeomorphism of boundaries of neighborhoods of a point and its image? And do results of removing balls remain non-homeomorphic?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Yes.  Make your homotopy equivalence $f$ smooth and let $q$ be a regular value of $f$.  Then $f$ is a local diffeomorphism at any point of $f^{-1}(q)$.

Comment: (and for your second question, you can just glue the balls back in and extend a homeomorphism over the glued-in balls).

Comment: @AndyPutman OK with the second, thanks. But - sorry - one more question about the first: why is it always smoothable?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Every continuous map between smooth manifolds is homotopic to a smooth map.

Comment: @AndyPutman Oh I see, thanks. No more questions :)

Comment: @AndyPutman In fact I did not notice - no smooth structures are involved in the question, it is about topological manifolds.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Yes, but since all 3-manifolds can be given smooth structures it is harmless to use them.  If you want to avoid smooth manifold topology for some reason (e.g. for certain examples in higher dimensions, though even there it is easy to come up with examples that happen to have smooth structures), the assertion about every continuous map between $n$-manifolds is homotopic to a map that is a local homeomorphism at some point is also true in the topological category.  I just gave the proof in the smooth category since it is 1 sentence as opposed to 3-4 sentences.